# How to augment search function to include array within objects

Tags: arrays, object, search, filter, vue.js

Given data in this format:

```
// projects.json
{
    businessName: "",
    address: "",
    city: "",
    reference: "",
    contacts: [
        {
            name: ""
            phone: ""
        },
        {
            name: ""
            phone: ""
        }
    ],
}
```

... and a search function (btw, this is a Vue app) which iterates the 'project' objects of the json:

```
export default {
    computed: {
        filteredProjects: function() {
            const searchTerm = this.search.toLowerCase();
            if (!searchTerm) {
                return false;
            }
            return this.projects.filter((project) => {
                return (project.businessName.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm)) ||
                         (project.reference.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm));
            });
        }
    } // computed
} // export default
```

... how can I augment this function to include in the search the 'contacts' array within each 'project' object, e.g.:

```
return this.projects.filter((project) => {
    return (project.businessName.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm)) ||
             (project.reference.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm)) ||
             // PSEUDO-CODE (searching contact name doesn't throw error but returns 100% of the data):
             (project.contacts.filter((el) => {
                 el.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm);
             }))
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions,

Whiskey T.

Comment: `(projects.contacts.filter(.....).length > 0)`

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for the response. As your suggestion shows closed parens around the filter arg, I assume you mean:
  '(project.contacts.filter((el) =>{
  el.name.toLowerCase().match(searchTerm);
 }).length > 0); ... but this is not returning any results where expected. What have I misunderstood? Thx

Comment: You need a `return` in front of `el.name`

Comment: @RoyJ Thank you; yet another 'duh' moment as to the 'return' ... however would you mind explaining why the length method is required on the contacts filter but not in the filter of the outer objects?

Comment: Because `filter` returns an array, which is a truthy value even if it's empty. The other expressions are using `match`.

Comment: @RoyJ Got it, many thanks again! p.s. if you port your comment to an 'answer' I'll gladly mark it as 'best/accepted'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. `filter` returns an array, so its value will always be true; you need to check the `length` of it to get a false value when it's empty
2. you need a `return` in your `project.contacts.filter` arrow function